# Do Updates Make speed of system slower?

Tags: updates

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04
should i download and install all of security updates? (about 500 MB)
if i do it , it doesn't make system speed slower?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you **should always install** any security update to protect your system (Linux can have many vulnerabilities).
If you maintain your system updated it will function well and offer you a ***nice*** experience.
You should not experience a slow down, **don't be afraid of a security update**: they are small changes, because *programmers can make mistakes* which needs to be fixed.
Good evening.